# Have I adjusted for predictors I use as random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, inference, random-effects-model, glmm

I believe this is a rather straight forward question.

I just read a research article in which it stated that: *"[...] we used study centre as random effect, which also means that we adjusted for study centre"*.

would then the same apply to Cox models? We are able to introduce random effects into Cox models, but does that automatically imply that we've adjusted for those variables (used as frailty terms).

**But is this really correct?** I.e have we automatically adjusted for variables which we introduce as random effects in mixed models?

Grateful for any input.